# How to using this function multiple times JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use this function multiple times, but it working just for first element.
Don't know what I doing wrong.
I probably need to use some loop but I don't know how
I tried to do for each div but it didn't work either

```
<span style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <span id="circle-days" class="circle-time"></span>
        </span>
        <span style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <span id="circle-hours" class="circle-time"></span>
        </span>
        <span style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <span id="circle-minutes" class="circle-time"></span>
        </span>
        <span id="circle-seconds" class="circle-time"></span>      
        <span id="timer"></span>
        <span><p>
        Do dostawy w najbliższą sobotę
        </p></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek, hour) {
      var resultDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);
   resultDate.setHours(hour,0,0,0);
    return resultDate;
}

var countDownDate = getNextDayOfWeek(new Date(),4,12);

// Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toString();
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toString();
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)).toString();
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000).toString();
$('#zegarki').each(function(index) {
      document.getElementById("circle-days").innerHTML = days + "<div class='timer-font'>Días</div>";
  document.getElementById("circle-hours").innerHTML = hours + "<div class='timer-font'>Hrs</div>";
  document.getElementById("circle-minutes").innerHTML = minutes + "<div class='timer-font'>Min</div>";
  document.getElementById("circle-seconds").innerHTML = seconds + "<div class='timer-font'>Seg</div>";
});
  // Display the result in the element with id="timer"


  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Id's are unique, so there should only ever be one to begin with (Assuming you're talking about `$('#zegarki').each(...)` ) Potentially helpful reading: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: i can add in each ID number example zegarki-1 zegarki-2, but how to distinguish them

Comment: Just use a class, and then use `$(this)` inside the `.each` to select the currently matched element

Comment: $(".zegarki").each(function() { } like this?

Comment: Also check your HTML, it has errors too. You can't have a `<p>` tag inside a `<span>`

Comment: $('.zegarki').each(function () { } not working

Comment: Where zegarki is on diffrent pages it working, but if two elements have zegarki it display only for first div with zegarki